# "on" and "live" in jQuery 1.10.2

Tags: jquery, live, jquery-1.10

1.10.2 How to apply to newly created elements. Which were created by:

```
$('#ids').append('<div class="sel_option" value="'+i+'">'+i+'</div>');
```

How to catch a click?
Or how to create elements which could be addressed ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As your contents are `loaded dynamically` you can't access them `directly`.

At the load time i.e `DOM ready` dynamically loaded contents are not part of DOM.

So you have to use `event Delegation`.

So bind the event on the element which is present in the DOM at page load

```
$('#ids').on('click', '.sel_option', function () {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: To be global used, without caring about parent name yo can use
$(document).on('click', '.sel_option', function () {
alert('clicked');
});

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var content = $(document);

  content.delegate(".sel_option","click",function(){alert("Hello")});
  // with the delegate function, you can put any event in any element

});
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

Comment: ok, just use this : content.on("click",".sel_option",function(){alert("Hello")});